# How to call functions in ui_component Magento 2

Tags: magento2, uicomponent

I have created two dynamic rows one by DataProvider way and one by ui_component.In Ven\Mod\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\MyField getting currency symbol with this function.

In dynamic rows children I added:

```
'children' => [

            static::FIELD_PRICE_NAME => $this->getPriceFieldConfig(30)

        ]
```

and defined function as:

```
protected function getPriceFieldConfig($sortOrder)
{
return [
    'arguments' => [
        'data' => [
            'config' => [
                'label' => __('Amount'),
                'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                'component' => 'Magento_Catalog/js/components/custom-options-component',
                'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                'dataScope' => static::FIELD_PRICE_NAME,
                'dataType' => Number::NAME,
                'addbefore' => $this->getCurrencySymbol(),
                'addbeforePool' => $this->productOptionsPrice->prefixesToOptionArray(),
                'sortOrder' => $sortOrder,
                'validation' => [
                    'validate-number' => true
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
}
```

and defined

> 'addbefore' => $this->getCurrencySymbol(),

function as:

```
protected function getCurrencySymbol()
{
    return $this->storeManager->getStore()->getBaseCurrency()->getCurrencySymbol();
}
```

Same in screen shot(By DataProvider):
[image]
Below is screen shot of dynamic rows created by ui_component way:
[image]

I have xml code at Ven/Mod/view/adminhtml/ui_component/product_form.xml as Form fields like:

```
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="testingproduct">    
           <field name="min_val">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Amount</item>
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
                        <item name="source" xsi:type="string">faq</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I want to know how can I get currency symbol in Amount field dynamic row created by DataProvider way into the Amount field created using ui_component.

It will be highly appreciated if you can give code example.
Thanks